# Converting NSString to NSNumber results in too many digits and strange rounding

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

When converting an `NSString`, which contains standard decimal numbers with two digits (e.g. 8.20) to a `NSNumber`, I get (from time to time) extra digits and a strange rounding behavior when logging the result via `NSLog` or saving it in Core Data (as float or double), e.g. 8.20 -> 8.199999999999999.

This is the code I am using to convert the numbers:

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];
 NSNumber *num = [numberFormatter numberFromString:str];
```

I do not understand why the conversion to NSNumber messes the number up. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Ask your professor to explain "floating point".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how float and double behaves in C/Objective-C (and many other languages). For example, when you type into python 8.0, the result would be 8.000000000001. I recommend using [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert them into primitive number types (double, float).

Comment: But would it be correct if Core Data stored 8.00000001 instead of 8.0?

Comment: Put another way - there is no way for a double precision floating point number to represent most common fractions exactly. All you know is the number you put in - number you get out should be accurate to within about one part in 10^15.

Comment: Correct. That's why it is recommended not to compare two floats/double using ==. (`float1 == float2` is bad. `Abs(float1 - float2) <= epsilon` is good.)

Comment: @AlexR: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html if you want to understand why this is correct behavior. If you don't want to read that, then just accept that it's true.

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying this. You were very helpful. Since the data I am dealing with is mostly currency data, I am now using NSDecimalNumber instead of float and double. What are your thoughts on NSDecimalNumber?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use NSNumberFormatter to convert string to float, it would be an overkill, 
To convert it just use

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[str floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter the problem when I use NSNumber to save the doublevalue
of 8.28 always show the 8.2799999999...,I guess it cause by a computer numerical precision
Try this code.

```
 + (NSString *)dealWithDouble:(double)doubleValue {
        double d2 = doubleValue;
        NSString *d2Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", d2];
        NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:d2Str];
        NSString *str2D = [num stringValue];
        return str2D;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floatValue. floatValue only gives 24 bit of precision. doubleValue gives 53 bits of precision. If you use numbers over a million dollars for example, floatValue cannot give you any values that are closer than six cent apart. ($1,000,000 followed by $1,000,000.06 etc. )

The rule is: Don't use float unless you *know* a reason why you should use float and not double.

Comment: Using doubles for currency calculations is also very wrong and stupid. `fixed` precision must be used for currency.

Comment: Using double for currency calculations is absolutely fine if you know what you are doing and avoid superstition.